# In wxPython, how to periodically repaint?

Tags: wxpython

I want my GUI to refresh (repaint) every second, so I set a timer to call my draw_all() periodically. However, it actually doesn't draw anything on the canvas. Anyone knows the reason? or just a better way to do this?

```
def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.init_canvas)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.draw_all, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def init_canvas(self, _):
        print('here')
        self._canvas = wx.PaintDC(self)

    def draw_all(self, _):
        print("there")
        self._canvas.do_stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put something on the canvas!

```
import wx
class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.init_canvas)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.draw_all, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()
        self.Colour="RED"

    def init_canvas(self, _):
        print('here')
        self._canvas = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self._canvas.SetDeviceOrigin(30, 240)
        self._canvas.SetAxisOrientation(True, True)
        self._canvas.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.Colour))
        self._canvas.DrawRectangle(1, 1, 300, 200)

    def draw_all(self, _):
        if self.Colour == "RED":
            self.Colour = "BLUE"
        else:
            self.Colour = "RED"
        self._canvas.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.Colour))
        self._canvas.DrawRectangle(1, 1, 300, 200)
        print (self.Colour)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Test(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```